# How to collect the real and imaginary parts and make it into two equations

Tags: complex

I have an equation which consists of a real and complex quantity I just wanted to separate it out and form two new equations.

```
e[1] = ComplexExpand[
   L1*Exp[I*x1] + L2*Exp[I*x2] - L4*Exp[I*x4] - L3*Exp[I*x3]];
```

Comment: Have your tried `ReIm`?

Comment: I have Tried Collect[e[1],I]

Comment: in short: `ComplexExpand@
 ReIm[L1*Exp[I*x1] + L2*Exp[I*x2] - L4*Exp[I*x4] - L3*Exp[I*x3]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ComplexExpand[{Re[#], Im[#]} &[L1*Exp[I*x1] + L2*Exp[I*x2] - L4*Exp[I*x4] - L3*Exp[I*x3]],
TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]
(*{L1 Cos[x1] + L2 Cos[x2] - L3 Cos[x3] - L4 Cos[x4], 
L1 Sin[x1] + L2 Sin[x2] - L3 Sin[x3] - L4 Sin[x4]}*)
```

Comment: Or more compactly, `ComplexExpand[
 ReIm[L1*Exp[I*x1] + L2*Exp[I*x2] - L4*Exp[I*x4] - L3*Exp[I*x3]]]`